# Select users where match then search a second table

Tags: mysql, sql

Just wondering if anyone could help with the select statement.
I want to select from a table in an mysql database then I want to join to another table and find corresponding matches for another field.
Currently I have the following select statement:
`select * FROM users WHERE user='marketing' OR user='sales';`

I want to use this, then I want to search based on 'user' and find another matching value in table2 called 'total'. There may not always be a user in table2, in this case I want 'total' to be blank for that user.

I think I could use a left join for this but not sure how to implement it.
Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: You are right. Now, go on. Try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you help guys. I have it working. Heres what I used: `select users.user, table2.total FROM users LEFT JOIN table2 on users.user = table2.total WHERE users.user = 'marketing' OR users.user = 'sales';`

Answer (score -1):

If you want second table you must at least try to include in the SELECT either with some sort of JOIN or without it, e.g. `SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.userid=table2.userid`

Comment: OK, so I have performed the following command: `select users.user, table2.total FROM users, table2 WHERE users.user='marketing' OR user.user='sales';`
This will return every user in the user table and it will match to a user in table2 and will bring back the total for each user recorded in table2. 
If however there is no user in table2, this will bring back the missing user and will give that user a total of another user that is in there.
What I really want to do is if there is no user recorded in table2 yet, I want to give the missing user a total of 0 to begin with.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Now provide a link from table1 to table2 and put it in the WHERE clause under AND condition